# Login functions WP

Tags: php, wordpress, google-signin

I am creating a wordpress plugin that shows a login with google button when logging in to the dashboard.

I am using platform.js and created my client id form google I am retrieving the user details and started their session by checking the details from database by custom sql query.

I wanted to know if there is any inbuilt function in wordpress that checks the details and start the session of the user?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an inbuilt function which does that. Function name is `wp_signon`

This function authenticates details of user and logs that user in which creates a session for that user.

Here is reference link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/

I hope this helps you.